# How can I detect the pressing of the Command or Option Key and the return key at the same time with ngKeypress?

Tags: angularjs

I know I can do something like this:

```
<div class="contentView"
 ng-keypress="phs.keyEnter($event)">

keyEnter = ($event): void => {
    var a = $event;
    var b = $event.keyCode;
}
```

But is there a way that I can detect if both the Command or Option key is pressed at the same time as the Return key?

Answer (score 0):

The $event indicates some keys that were simultaneously pressed (such as ctrl, alt...). 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/MouseEvent.
Not sure about cmd, but check it out.

You can also combine ngKeypress & ngKeyup to check when cmd key was pressed and return key was released and determine when those events overlap.