# How can I position my cursor in an input field based on a keypress?

Tags: angularjs

I am capturing keypresses like this:

```
<div class="contentView"
     ng-keypress="phs.keyEnter($event)">

keyEnter = ($event): void => {
    var a = $event;
```

How can I make it so that clicking a key will make the cursor go to an input field:

```
 <input ng-change="phs.englishChange();"
               ng-model="phs.english"
               ng-model-options="{ debounce: 750 }"
               style="width:6rem;"
               type="text" />
```

Comment: isn't this an extension to your previous question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48483667 ?

Comment: What do you mean by "clicking a key"? Just pressing a key on the keyboard?

Comment: What is the structure? Us your `input` inside of the `div class="contentView"`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think [`directive`](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) can help us to have a more universal and re-usable solution to your problem, because it is the most good place to attach a specified behavior to that `input` element. So here is a custom `doOnKeypress` directive that accepts a key (`doOnKeypress`) and an optional callback (`acceptOn`) to check the target of the fired [`keypress` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/keypress) and a callback (`onKeypress`) that is going to be fired if all conditions are satisfied.

In the example below the `input` will be focused whenever <kbd>a</kbd> keyboard button is pressed. I left the comments so you can modify it for your needs (hope the general idea is clear):

```js
angular.module("app", [])
    .controller("TestController", ["$scope", function ($scope) {
        $scope.acceptOn = function (target, element) {
            console.log(target);     // you can make any checks for target by passing this into a directive
            return element[0] !== target[0]; //target is not the same input element
        };
        $scope.focusOn = function (element) {
            element[0].focus(); // or whatever you want with element
        };
    }]).directive('doOnKeypress', ['$document', function ($document) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            doOnKeypress: '@',
            acceptOn: '&?',
            onKeypress: '&'
        },
        link: function postLink(scope, element) {

            function keypress(e) {
                var target = angular.element(e.target);
                var targetIsAcceptable = angular.isFunction(scope.acceptOn) ? scope.acceptOn({
                    target: target,
                    element: element
                }) : true; // add the condition to test the target
                var specialKeyPressed = e.shiftKey || e.ctrlKey || e.altKey || e.metaKey; // in case you need to check any special keys

                if (targetIsAcceptable && !specialKeyPressed) {
                    var keyCode = e.which || e.keyCode;
                    var key = String.fromCharCode(keyCode);
                    if ("*" === scope.doOnKeypress || key.toLowerCase() === scope.doOnKeypress.toLowerCase()) {  // any check before focusing  (lets say * - is any key)
                        e.preventDefault(); // prevent from typing into the input
                        scope.onKeypress({element: element});
                    }
                }
            }

            $document.on('keypress', keypress);

            scope.$on('$destroy', function () {
                $document.off('keypress', keypress);
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.7/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="app" class="">
  <div ng-controller="TestController" class='listen-to-keypress'>
   TestController

   <br/>
    
   <div>
   
    <input ng-change="phs.englishChange();"
               ng-model="phs.english"
               ng-model-options="{ debounce: 750 }"
               style="width:6rem;"
               do-on-keypress='A'
               accept-on='acceptOn(target, element)'
               on-keypress='focusOn(element)'
               type="text" />
   
   </div>

  </div>
</body>
```

**UPDATE:** added `element` argument to the `acceptOn` callback to allow to compare target with the same element, since we want to let the user typing into this `input` element in our case.

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<input value="_sample input value" ng-click="getCur_Pos($e)" ng-keyup="getCur_Pos($e)"/>
    <div> Cursor Pos : <b ng-bind="curPos_Val"></b></div>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
$scope.getCur_Pos = function($e) {
   $scope.doCar_Position($e.target);  
};

$scope.doCar_Position = function(o_Fld) {
var _Crt_Pos = 0;
if (o_Fld.selectionStart || o_Fld.selectionStart == '0')
  _Crt_Pos = o_Fld.selectionStart;
// Return results
$scope.curPos_Val = _Crt_Pos;
```

};